Unable to render image in farcaster frame
The code is not throwing any error, also it fetches AI generated image from huggingface api and console log image data value, but the image is not rendering on farcaster frame, What could be reason? I am using frog-fm frame for creating frames, and beginner in next.js.
Any help appreciated thanks!
    /** @jsxImportSource frog/jsx */
    import { Button, Frog, TextInput } from 'frog'
    import { devtools } from 'frog/dev'
    // import { neynar } from 'frog/hubs'
    import { handle } from 'frog/next'
    import { serveStatic } from 'frog/serve-static'
    import axios from 'axios'

    const app = new Frog({
      assetsPath: '/',
      basePath: '/api',
      // Supply a Hub to enable frame verification.
      // hub: neynar({ apiKey: 'NEYNAR_FROG_FM' })
    })

    // Uncomment to use Edge Runtime
    // export const runtime = 'edge'

    app.frame('/', (c) => {
      const { buttonValue, inputText, status } = c
      const imgdescription = inputText

      let imageData: Uint8Array | null = null;
      

      const createImage = async () => {

        const URL = `https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2`
      
        const response = await axios({
          url: URL,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_HUGGING_FACE_API_KEY}`,
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          data: JSON.stringify({
            inputs: imgdescription, options: { wait_for_model: true },
          }),
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        })
      
        const type = response.headers['content-type'] // server is giveing the image type as jpeg.
        const data = response.data
      
        const base64data = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')
        const img = `data:${type};base64,` + base64data // <-- This is so we can render it on the page
        console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", img);
        console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", data);
        return data
      }

      if (status === 'response') {
        createImage().then(data => {
          imageData = data;
          console.log("1111111111111111111111", data)
          c.res({
            image: renderContent()
          });
        });
      }

      const renderContent = () => {
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              background:
                status === 'response'
                  ? 'linear-gradient(to right, #432889, #17101F)'
                  : 'black',
              backgroundSize: '100% 100%',
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              flexWrap: 'nowrap',
              height: '100%',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              textAlign: 'center',
              width: '100%',
            }}
          >
            <div>  
              { imageData ? (
                <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`} alt="Generated Image" />
              ) : (
                'Welcome!'
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      };

      return c.res({
        image: renderContent(),
        intents: [
          <TextInput placeholder="Enter custom fruit..." />,
          <Button value="abc" >Generate Image</Button>,
          status === 'response' && <Button.Reset>Reset</Button.Reset>,
        ],
      })
    })

    devtools(app, { serveStatic })

    export const GET = handle(app)
    export const POST = handle(app)

I tried solving this issue via chat gpt and gemmini but nothing works.

You could try:
image: () => renderContent(),

Instead of:
image: renderContent(),


It's giving syntax error.
